# Cannot get HTTP header

Tags: http, dictionary, go, header

I don't understand why `func (h Header) Get(key string) string` in package `http` in file `header.go` doens't work as expected.

I want to get the header "SOAPAction" regardless of its casing, but I only get an empty string `""`. The direct access works as expected.

```golang
soapAction1 := r.Header.Get("SOAPAction")
soapAction2 := r.Header["SOAPAction"]

fmt.Println("soapAction1: ", soapAction1, " , soapAction2:", soapAction2)

// Got:      soapAction:              , soapAction2: [MySoapHeader]
// Expected: soapAction: MySoapHeader , soapAction2: [MySoapHeader]
```

```golang
// Get gets the first value associated with the given key. If
// there are no values associated with the key, Get returns "".
// It is case insensitive; textproto.CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey is
// used to canonicalize the provided key. To use non-canonical keys,
// access the map directly.
func (h Header) Get(key string) string {
    return textproto.MIMEHeader(h).Get(key)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get) (emphasis added):

> Get gets the first value associated with the given key. If there are no values associated with the key, Get returns "". It is case insensitive; **textproto.CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey is used to canonicalize the provided key. To use non-canonical keys, access the map directly.**

Your header, `SOAPAction`, is not cannonical, so you have two choices:

1. Use the canonical version (`Soapaction`)
2. Use direct access, as the documentation explains, and as you have done.

Answer (score 2):

`http.Header.Get` method relies on a string transformation to fetch the value for a given string.

The transformation is implemented by the `textproto` package

https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey

> CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey returns the canonical format of the MIME header
> key s. The canonicalization converts the first letter and any letter
> following a hyphen to upper case; **the rest are converted to lowercase**.

You can try it yourself:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/textproto"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(textproto.CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey("SOAPAction"))
}
```

It prints: `Soapaction`